# Why getjson only work in firefox

Tags: javascript, json

These are the codes:

```
var url = "basic.json";

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    var items = [];

    $.each(data.CaseResult, function(key, val) {

        items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
        alert(items);
    });

    $('<ul/>', {
        'class': 'my-new-list',
        html: items.join('')
    }).appendTo('body');

});
```

i use the local file "basic.json", this works in firefox with `jquery 1.3.2-min.js` but nor `jquery 1.8.2.js`. And it dosen't work in chrome,IE with both js files.
Why? 
After that, I have tried these codes with `jquery 1.8.2.js`, it works

```
   var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20WHERE%20symbol%3D'COL'&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    var items = [];

    $.each(data.query.results.quote, function(key, val) {

        items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
    });

    $('<ul/>', {
        'class': 'my-new-list',
        html: items.join('')
    }).appendTo('body');

});
```

Who can tell me what is the differences between the differet version of jquery files, why one works but another one not? and why it does not work by local json file without firefox browser? So strange.

Comment: 1.3.2? thats a really old version of jquery you compare it with. $.getJSON returns different types of objects first of all between the two versions. Second of all, other updates have happened to make jQuery as a whole more cross browser compatible with MODERN broswer versions. Browsers may have made changes that cause jQuery 1.3.2 not to work in expected ways with those browsers. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: It "doesn't work"?  What errors are you getting in your console?

Comment: the first code, i use the 1.8.2 version , the getjson function seems not called, no response. Even if i add a alert() in the getjson function, it does not run. Or do you give me an download address version of jquery.js which the getjson function can work with local file